# Enumerate multi set of all elements from given list which sums up to given number

Tags: prolog

Given a number N and a list, I want to enumerate all ways to select numbers from the list so that their sum equals N. I can use numbers from the list multiple times. I thought of logic roughly corresponding to following tree:

[image]

I came up with following code:

```
append([], Y, [Y]).  %append[] and Y to get Y.
append([H|X], Y, [H|Z]) :- append(X, Y, Z). % append [H|X] and Y to get [H|Z] if appending X and Y gives Z

ss(0, [], Ans).

ss(N, L, Ans) :-
    ss1(N, 0, L, [], Ans). 

ss1(N, N1, [], L2, Ans) :- 
    N == N1, 
    Ans = L2.

ss1(N, N1, L, L1, Ans) :-
    N == N1,
    Ans = L2.

ss1(N, N1, L, L1, Ans) :- 
    [A | B] = L,
    N2 is (A+N1),
    append(L1, A, L2),
    N >= N2,
    ss1(N, N2, L, L2, Ans).

ss1(N, N1, L, L1, Ans) :- 
    [A, B | C] = L,
    N2 is (B+N1),
    append(L1, B, L2),
    N >= N2,
    ss1(N, N2, L, L2, Ans).
```

Running it gives following:

```
?- ss(20, [5, 8, 13, 10, 2], Ans). 
   Call: (10) cc(20, [5, 8, 13, 10, 2], _3530) ? creep
   Call: (11) cc1(20, 0, [5, 8, 13, 10, 2], [], _3530) ? creep
   Call: (12) 20==0 ? creep
   Fail: (12) 20==0 ? creep
   Redo: (11) cc1(20, 0, [5, 8, 13, 10, 2], [], _3530) ? creep
   Call: (12) [5, 8, 13, 10, 2]=[_4130|_4132] ? creep
   Exit: (12) [5, 8, 13, 10, 2]=[5, 8, 13, 10, 2] ? creep
   Call: (12) _4282 is 5+0 ? creep
   Exit: (12) 5 is 5+0 ? creep
   Call: (12) append([], 5, _4374) ? creep
   Exit: (12) append([], 5, [5]) ? creep
   Call: (12) 20>=5 ? creep
   Exit: (12) 20>=5 ? creep
   Call: (12) cc1(20, 5, [5, 8, 13, 10, 2], [5], _3530) ? creep
   Call: (13) 20==5 ? creep
   Fail: (13) 20==5 ? creep
   Redo: (12) cc1(20, 5, [5, 8, 13, 10, 2], [5], _3530) ? creep
   Call: (13) [5, 8, 13, 10, 2]=[_4676|_4678] ? creep
   Exit: (13) [5, 8, 13, 10, 2]=[5, 8, 13, 10, 2] ? creep
   Call: (13) _4828 is 5+5 ? creep
   Exit: (13) 10 is 5+5 ? creep
   Call: (13) append([5], 5, _4920) ? creep
   Call: (14) append([], 5, _4910) ? creep
   Exit: (14) append([], 5, [5]) ? creep
   Exit: (13) append([5], 5, [5, 5]) ? creep
   Call: (13) 20>=10 ? creep
   Exit: (13) 20>=10 ? creep
   Call: (13) cc1(20, 10, [5, 8, 13, 10, 2], [5, 5], _3530) ? creep
   Call: (14) 20==10 ? creep
   Fail: (14) 20==10 ? creep
   Redo: (13) cc1(20, 10, [5, 8, 13, 10, 2], [5, 5], _3530) ? creep
   Call: (14) [5, 8, 13, 10, 2]=[_5316|_5318] ? creep
   Exit: (14) [5, 8, 13, 10, 2]=[5, 8, 13, 10, 2] ? creep
   Call: (14) _5468 is 5+10 ? creep
   Exit: (14) 15 is 5+10 ? creep
   Call: (14) append([5, 5], 5, _5560) ? creep
   Call: (15) append([5], 5, _5550) ? creep
   Call: (16) append([], 5, _5600) ? creep
   Exit: (16) append([], 5, [5]) ? creep
   Exit: (15) append([5], 5, [5, 5]) ? creep
   Exit: (14) append([5, 5], 5, [5, 5, 5]) ? creep
   Call: (14) 20>=15 ? creep
   Exit: (14) 20>=15 ? creep
   Call: (14) cc1(20, 15, [5, 8, 13, 10, 2], [5, 5, 5], _3530) ? creep
   Call: (15) 20==15 ? creep
   Fail: (15) 20==15 ? creep
   Redo: (14) cc1(20, 15, [5, 8, 13, 10, 2], [5, 5, 5], _3530) ? creep
   Call: (15) [5, 8, 13, 10, 2]=[_6050|_6052] ? creep
   Exit: (15) [5, 8, 13, 10, 2]=[5, 8, 13, 10, 2] ? creep
   Call: (15) _6202 is 5+15 ? creep
   Exit: (15) 20 is 5+15 ? creep
   Call: (15) append([5, 5, 5], 5, _6294) ? creep
   Call: (16) append([5, 5], 5, _6284) ? creep
   Call: (17) append([5], 5, _6334) ? creep
   Call: (18) append([], 5, _6384) ? creep
   Exit: (18) append([], 5, [5]) ? creep
   Exit: (17) append([5], 5, [5, 5]) ? creep
   Exit: (16) append([5, 5], 5, [5, 5, 5]) ? creep
   Exit: (15) append([5, 5, 5], 5, [5, 5, 5, 5]) ? creep
   Call: (15) 20>=20 ? creep
   Exit: (15) 20>=20 ? creep
   Call: (15) cc1(20, 20, [5, 8, 13, 10, 2], [5, 5, 5, 5], _3530) ? creep
   Call: (16) 20==20 ? creep
   Exit: (16) 20==20 ? creep
   Call: (16) true ? creep
   Exit: (16) true ? creep
   Exit: (15) cc1(20, 20, [5, 8, 13, 10, 2], [5, 5, 5, 5], _3530) ? creep
   Exit: (14) cc1(20, 15, [5, 8, 13, 10, 2], [5, 5, 5], _3530) ? creep
   Exit: (13) cc1(20, 10, [5, 8, 13, 10, 2], [5, 5], _3530) ? creep
   Exit: (12) cc1(20, 5, [5, 8, 13, 10, 2], [5], _3530) ? creep
   Exit: (11) cc1(20, 0, [5, 8, 13, 10, 2], [], _3530) ? creep
   Exit: (10) cc(20, [5, 8, 13, 10, 2], _3530) ? creep
true .
```

As you can see, it forms the list `[5,5,5,5]` which sums to 20. But instead of returning it, it returns `true`, despite we equate it with `Ans`. It also need to return sets: `[5,5,10],[10,10],[2,2,2,2,2,10],[2,8,10],[2,2,2,2,2,2,8],[2,2,8,8]`.

Why so? Also is there any simpler logic possible?

([ref](https://github.com/jdan/code/blob/master/prolog/subset_sum.pl) for `append()`)

Comment: ERROR: Undefined procedure: cc/3 (DWIM could not correct goal) I guess you want to ask `ss(20, [5, 8, 13, 10, 2], Ans).`

Comment: @tiffi yes you are correct. weirdly, it is not allowing me to edit!!

Comment: don't worry, I tried to edit it now.

Comment: darn, I only edited the question - now it is not consistent with the trace :-)

Comment: It shows `Edit(1)` to me. When I click on it, it says "Approve, reject, or improve this suggested edit." on grey pop up background without any other UI element. :-\

Comment: maybe we need to wait for an admin or so to approve former edits - don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phew, there is a lot to say, so let's start:

your definition of `append/3` is pretty unorthodox and in some systems, you are not allowed to redefine `append/3`, which is in-built (and differs from your definition), so let's change that to `append2/3` for now:

```
append2([], Y, [Y]). 
append2([H|X], Y, [H|Z]) :- append2(X, Y, Z).
```

You don't need `ss(0, [], Ans)`, so let's skip this.

We keep:

```
ss(N, L, Ans) :-
    ss1(N, 0, L, [], Ans).
```

Let's have a look at the next two clauses, your base clauses for ss1:

```
ss1(N, N1, [], L2, Ans) :- 
    N == N1, 
    Ans = L2.

ss1(N, N1, L, L1, Ans) :-
    N == N1,
    Ans = L2.
```

In the second clause - where is the prolog system supposed to take `L2` from? Also, we do not need two clauses to express what your aiming at, one suffices:

```
ss1(N, N, _, L1, L1).
```

We leave the next two clauses for a second (only having renamed `append/3`):

```
ss1(N, N1, L, L1, Ans) :- 
    [A | B] = L,
    N2 is (A+N1),
    append2(L1, A, L2),
    N >= N2,
    ss1(N, N2, L, L2, Ans).

ss1(N, N1, L, L1, Ans) :- 
    [A, B | C] = L,
    N2 is (B+N1),
    append2(L1, B, L2),
    N >= N2,
    ss1(N, N2, L, L2, Ans).
```

So, we now have the program

```
append2([], Y, [Y]). 
append2([H|X], Y, [H|Z]) :- append2(X, Y, Z).

ss(N, L, Ans) :- ss1(N, 0, L, [], Ans).

ss1(N, N, _, L1, L1).           % clause 1 for ss1
ss1(N, N1, L, L1, Ans) :-       % clause 2 for ss1
    [A | B] = L,
    N2 is (A+N1),
    append2(L1, A, L2),
    N >= N2,
    ss1(N, N2, L, L2, Ans).
ss1(N, N1, L, L1, Ans) :-       %clause 3 for ss1
    [A, B | C] = L,
    N2 is (B+N1),
    append2(L1, B, L2),
    N >= N2,
    ss1(N, N2, L, L2, Ans).
```

Now, we get:

```
?- ss(20, [5, 8, 13, 10, 2], Ans).
Ans = [5, 5, 5, 5] ;
```

We also get:

```
?- ss(0, [5, 8, 13, 10, 2], Ans).
Ans = [] ;
```

We even get:

```
?- ss(4,[1,2],Ans).
Ans = [1, 1, 1, 1] ;
Ans = [1, 1, 2] ;
Ans = [1, 2, 1] ;
Ans = [2, 1, 1] ;
Ans = [2, 2] ;
```

So, that's way progress. But the problem is, that in clauses 2 and 3 for `ss1/5`, we only look at the first elements of the list to pick from, so we still have to solve this ;-)

One solution is to replace clauses 2 and 3 for `ss1/5` by one single clause:

```
ss1(N, N1, L, L1, Ans) :-      
    member(A,L),
    N2 is (A+N1),
    append2(L1, A, L2),
    N >= N2,
    ss1(N, N2, L, L2, Ans).
```

`member/2` is built-in in many prolog systems, if it is not in yours, it is easy to define.

Now, we still have a problem if 0 is not the last member of the list - then we get into an endless loop, for example

```
?- ss(1, [0,1],Ans).
?- ss(2, [3,0,1],Ans).
```

Let's therefore ignore 0s and only enumerate sums of integers >0.
From your comments, I also get that you want to enumerate each multiset only once. Here's a solution:

```
ss(N, L, Ans) :- 
    sort(L,S), 
    reverse(S,R), 
    ss1(N, 0, R, [], Ans). 
 ss1(N, N, _, L, L) :- !. 
 ss1(N, N1, [H|T], L1, Ans) :- 
    H > 0, 
    N2 is H+N1, 
    N>=N2, 
    ss1(N, N2, [H|T], [H|L1], Ans). 
 ss1(N, N1, [_|T], L1, Ans) :- 
    ss1(N, N1, T, L1, Ans).
```

If you want to allow 0s or negative integers in the list, please indicate in your comments - then this needs to be fixed.

To your inital question, we now get:

```
?- ss(20, [5, 8, 13, 10, 2], Ans).
Ans = [2, 5, 13] ;
Ans = [10, 10] ;
Ans = [2, 8, 10] ;
Ans = [5, 5, 10] ;
Ans = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 10] ;
Ans = [2, 2, 8, 8] ;
Ans = [2, 5, 5, 8] ;
Ans = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8] ;
Ans = [5, 5, 5, 5] ;
Ans = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5] ;
Ans = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2|...] ;
false.
```

Since the last answer is too long to be shown this way, we can also ask:

```
?- ss(20, [5, 8, 13, 10, 2], Ans), write(Ans), nl,fail.
[2,5,13]
[10,10]
[2,8,10]
[5,5,10]
[2,2,2,2,2,10]
[2,2,8,8]
[2,5,5,8]
[2,2,2,2,2,2,8]
[5,5,5,5]
[2,2,2,2,2,5,5]
[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
false.
```

Comment: Am guessing which of changes you did till first output `[5,5,5,5]` fixed issue in my program that it was simply returned `true` instead of `[5,5,5,5]`. I guess its just incorrect `L2` instead of `L1`.  Changing `L2` to `L1` started giving `[5,5,5,5]`. Though other your point till your first output `[5,5,5,5]` are enlightening. I had  `[A | B] = L` and  `[A, B | C] = L`, because I wanted to follow that tree structure to somehow eliminate duplicate outputs like `[8,10,2]` and `[8,2,10]`. But that is not happening with both `[A | B] = L` and  `[A, B | C] = L` and `member(A,L)`, right? [cont...]

Comment: [continued from last comment] **Q1.** How can we eliminate such duplucates? **Q2.** I didnt get why, code till first output `[5,5,5,5]` gives all combinations for `ss(4,[1,2],Ans).`, but gives only `[5,5,5,5]` for `ss(20, [5, 8, 13, 10, 2], Ans).`

Comment: to answer Q2: check ?- ss(20, [5, 10, 8, 13, 2], Ans). As I have written in my answer, you only consider the first two elements of the list.

Comment: If we exclude 0 - which will lead to an infinite enumeration anyways, this is probably a good solution: ss(N, L, Ans) :- 
    sort(L,S),
    reverse(S,R),
    ss1(N, 0, R, [], Ans).
ss1(N, N, _, L, L) :- !. 
ss1(N, N1, [H|T], L1, Ans) :-
    H \=0,       
    N2 is H+N1,
    N>=N2,
    ss1(N, N2, [H|T], [H|L1], Ans).
ss1(N, N1, [_|T], L1, Ans) :-       
    ss1(N, N1, T, L1, Ans).